# Unity script to create assets one time only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a TCG (trading card game) in Unity as an University assignment. I have some scriptable objects to create different types of cards. The problem is I have 600+ cards so it would be nice to have a script that creates a card asset for every card and sets their parameters(load images, texts).

Is there any way to achieve this? It is important that the script runs only once, not every time I open the editor or I start a new instance of the game.

Comment: Yes there is a way. But we'll need more information. Where do the parameters coem from? Is there a database/XML/text file etc?

Comment: I have two options. Since the theme of the game is World Cup Russia 2018 I need some images with players, their name and their position. I found an API of EA Sports with all these details so I can make requests on that api to get information or I can make a script to download all the images locally, name then something like "Cristiano Ronaldo_ST" and get additional information from their name.

Comment: It's a better solution to use one prefab (we are talking about prefabs, not assets) instead of 600, and instead adjust that one prefab (the card) to receive the game properties, image, sounds, etc as needed. Or use more for different appearances. Loading the prefabs via name, which then have to be in the resource folder btw, is not recommended performance-wise.

Comment: @Battle I have prefabs for Player Card and Spell Card. By using your ideea, doesn’t mean i have to load the properties every time a card is used? I am new to unity and I don’t really understand all concepts. With card assets i load properties only one time, and a card asset is pretty small.

Comment: @Robet - Yes, let's say that these 2 prefabs are sufficient. When you want to give a player the spell "Fireball" you do the following: You know it's a spell, so you instantiate a Spell Card prefab. Then you assign that spell to it, so that internally you can read the effects, the costs, etc. Then you set up the exterior, which is visible to the player (name, costs, icon, description). In order to have such "spells" ready you have many options. One simple being just creating instances of a "Spell" class in your script and putting them into a list or preferably dictionary.

Comment: @Robet - Well, one issue with having 600 prefabs is that once you want to change all at once, it will be a huge pain. If you for example update visuals for Spell Cards - you'd have to apply that to all existing prefabs. Or otherwise you'd have to recreate all the prefabs. Also, 600 prefabs is quite something, and Unity would have to keep all of them loaded and *find* the matching one by name every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a method that is only called via a specific button in the UnityEditor that generates all your assets using the [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) attribute:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

    using System.IO;
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;

    public static class YourExtensions
    {
        [MenuItem("YourMenu/GenerateAssets")]
        private static void GenerateAssets()
        {
            // TODO Get and parse required information e.g. from Database / Xml or Text file
            // I'ld simply make a new class for that like "CardInformation"

            // List<CardInformation>() cardlist = new List<CardInformation>();


            // Somehow receive your information
            // cardlist.Add(new CardInformation(parameters));



            // TODO Generate Scriptableobjects

            // foreach(var cardInfo in cardlist)
            // {
                    YourScriptableObjectClass asset = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<YourScriptableObjectClass > ();

                    string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (Selection.activeObject);
                    if (path == "") 
                    {
                        path = "Assets";
                    } 
                    else if (Path.GetExtension (path) != "") 
                    {
                        path = path.Replace (Path.GetFileName (AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (Selection.activeObject)), "");
                    }

                    string assetPathAndName = AssetDatabase.GenerateUniqueAssetPath (path + "/New " + typeof(YourScriptableObjectClass ).ToString() + ".asset");

                    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset (asset, assetPathAndName);

                    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets ();
                    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
                    EditorUtility.FocusProjectWindow ();
                    Selection.activeObject = asset;

                    // TODO here set your passed parameters for this asset
                    // asset.parameter = cardInfo.parameters;

                    EditorUtility.SetDirty(asset);
            // } end foreach
        }

    }

#endif
```

Source for AssetCreation: [CreateScriptableObjectAsset](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CreateScriptableObjectAsset)

This method will never be called unless you click the Button in the top Menubar of the Unity Editor.

**Note:** You can skip the `#if UNITY_EDITOR` pre-processors if you simply place that script into a folder called `Editor`. Those scripts are automatically excluded from any build.